# ¿Existe objeto en memoria despues de eliminar el indice del vector en el que esta alojado?

Tags: c++, array, class

Tengo la siguiente clase

```
#pragma once


#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Unit
{
public:

    Unit();
    ~Unit();

    int ID;
    int range;
    std::string name;

    void Init(int,int,std::string);

};
```

Y el siguiente vector

```
std::vector<Unit> activeUnits;
```

A lo largo de la ejecucion del programa, el tamaño del vector variará mucho ya que estare constantemente añadiendo y eliminando diferentes objetos "Unit" dentro del vector, los cuales defino de la siguiente manera

```
activeUnits.emplace_back(1, 1, "test")
```

Como he dicho necesitare estar eliminando objetos del vector constantemente, de forma que el vector tambien cambie de tamaño
Para eliminar objetos del vector hago lo siguiente

```
 activeUnits.erase(activeUnits.begin() + index);
```

La duda que tengo es si al hacer esto estoy borrando tambien el objeto alojado en el indice que borro, o si este permanece en memoria, o si directamente estoy generando algun tipo de memory leak o parecido. En el caso de que esto sea así, existe alguna manera de controlar la eliminacion de objetos e indices del vector de alguna mejor manera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El contenedor `std::vector` tiene un comportamiento "*especial*" para seguir las exigencias redactadas en el estándar de C++, estas exigencias se pueden resumir con "*Los objetos contenidos deben estar alojados en memoria anexa*" (si quieres más detalles, [lee este artículo de Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230802-00/?p=108524)).

Este comportamiento implica que `std::vector` suele reservar más memoria de la que realmente está usando (para evitar realojar datos), es decir: tu `std::vector` de `Unit` tiene en su interior memoria reservada para almacenar `Unit` que *aún* no existen. Cuando borras un elemento de tu `std::vector` estás dejando una celda en ese mismo estado: Una zona de memoria preparada para almacenar un `Unit` pero que no almacena nada.

Por lo tanto, estás borrando bien los elementos de `std::vector`, no creas ninguna fuga de memoria; pero tal vez este contenedor no sea el adecuado para la tarea que abordas. Ya que:

> A lo largo de la ejecución del programa, el tamaño del vector variará mucho ya que estaré constantemente añadiendo y eliminando diferentes objetos "Unit" dentro del vector

Un `std::vector` se caracteriza por un alto rendimiento a la hora de recorrer los datos (por la garantía de que los datos están anexos), pero es de los contenedores menos eficientes para inserción y borrado de datos. Puedes mitigar ese problema pre-reservando memoria:

```
std::vector<Unit> datos;
datos.reserve(100000); // Muchos muchos datos.
```

Eso resolverá el problema de eficiencia cuando insertas datos, pero no cuando los borras de posiciones iniciales o intermedias. Si tu caso de uso es de más de insertar/borrar y menos de recorrer, te aconsejo que uses `std::list`. Para saber más de este tema te aconsejo leer [Five Advanced Initialization Techniques in C++](https://www.cppstories.com/2023/five-adv-init-techniques-cpp/).

Answer (score 0):

Las fugas de memoria se producen cuando te olvidas de liberar la memoria reservada. Son errores del programador.

`vector` y todos los contenedores de la librería estándar se encargan de manejar su propia memoria así que si no deberían causar fugas.

Si guardaras punteros en el vector, sí sería posible que por un descuido tuyo de produzcan fugas. Ya que el contenedor no libera la dirección de memoria a la que apuntan.

Para librarte de administrar tu memoria adecuadamente puedes utilizar [punteros inteligentes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Smart_pointers).

---

Aunque es cierto que cuando eliminas elementos del vector, la información permanece intacta. Puedes verlo en [este ejemplo](https://tio.run/##jYzfCoIwHIXv9xQHulH4FfTX0rUXiQibo0a6DZ3diM@@TCFvOzcHzsd3pHPLh5QhLLSRZVsocG0bX6u8Emze3kp6WwvGtPGocm2iGB3DkMYXaTphPkABgzM6rAkbwpawI@wJB0JCOKLPRsmsnHW3ey5fUZzNN9K2HpzDXJLrt8dRmaL8WW3znLTTn14fwgc).

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> n = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    n.pop_back();
    std::cout << n[7] << std::endl;
    n.push_back(9);
    std::cout << n[7] << std::endl;
}
```

El vector reserva memoria a medida que lo necesita. Este es un proceso lento, ya que además tiene que copiar todos los elementos al nuevo bloque y liberar el anterior.

Así que en lugar de reservar memoria para un solo elemento adicional, reserva para varios más y evita estar constantemente reservando memoria. En [este ejemplo](https://tio.run/##RYxNCsIwEIX3OcWAizYUiy5tYk8iSJxGDdpJSBNBpGePqYE6m8d87wed294QU9oYwmccNEhjp@C1Gnv2Zy@NwfqeMUMBRmWo5vBhkG8KQ9cVW2azBxI/frUe6iVt4Ag7kUXCftGm4aW5ttHGAFICtaicQhPeeT3/1YkqsUapdXG6ny8KH/WBFz6zOaUv) puedes ver que la capacidad se va duplicando.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        std::cout << n.capacity() << '\n';
        n.push_back(9);
    }
}
```

Puedes encontrar una explicación en [la documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

También te dejo [otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18067504/13419694) similar de Stackoverflow.